# What nuance does the が particle add in the following sentence? At what time would each sentence be more appropriate?

Tags: particles, particle-は, particle-が, は-and-が, subordinate-clauses

両親**は**結婚した時、どこにも行きませんでした。

VS

両親**が**結婚した時、どこにも行きませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

This is a sentence about the parents' honeymoon, right? In this case, は is the natural choice because 両親 is the shared topic of both verbs (結婚した and 行きませんでした). The latter sentence is a little puzzling because it sounds like 行きませんでした has an implicit subject that is different from 両親.

In general, use が when you want to specify a different subject in a subordinate clause, like this:

- 両親が結婚した時、日本は戦争中でした。
  <sub>(The two verbs have different subjects.)</sub>
- 夜が来たら電話します。
  <sub>(The implicit subject of 電話する is "I".)</sub>